# Getting black background after adding PNG transparent image for products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hello I am using Magento version 2.1.7. When I try to add any transparent PNG image to any product then in frontend it is displaying with black background instead of white. The image is not saving correctly in pub/media/catalog/product/cache. I have tried many solutions available but nothing is working and there are most of solution for magento 1.9 not for 2.1 . So Please help me to resolve this as I can't update my magento version.

FYI:The image uploaded:

[image: The image uploaded:]

The image in frontend:
[image]

Thank You